# Blob string url to PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, svg, blob

I am creating a blob url string which contains multiple SVGs

> blob:file%3A///45525ac9-caa6-4a48-aa8f-aab1ff6c9e7e

I am able to print this also using iframe.

```
function closePrint () {
  document.body.removeChild(this.__container__);
}

function setPrint () {
  this.contentWindow.__container__ = this;
  this.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = closePrint;
  this.contentWindow.onafterprint = closePrint;
  this.contentWindow.focus(); // Required for IE
  this.contentWindow.print();
}

function printPage (sURL) {
  var oHiddFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
  oHiddFrame.onload = setPrint;
  oHiddFrame.style.visibility = "hidden";
  oHiddFrame.style.position = "fixed";
  oHiddFrame.style.right = "0";
  oHiddFrame.style.bottom = "0";
  oHiddFrame.src = sURL;
  document.body.appendChild(oHiddFrame);
}

 printPage(fileURL);
```

But how can I download the same url content as PDF in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You're basically asking how to convert SVG to PDF, right? Either you do it serverside, or if you absolutely want to do it in JavaScript: take a look at [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/).

Comment: Basically, I have multiple SVGs inside a div and I want to export the whole thing as single PDF. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uehbhhwu/